# Shapes are not aligned sklearn.score

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

```
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.read_csv('train.csv')
X=np.array(df['x'],dtype=np.int)
Y=np.array(df['y'],dtype=np.float)
X=X.reshape(1,-1)
Y=Y.reshape(1,-1)
X=np.nan_to_num(X)
Y=np.nan_to_num(Y)
print(X.shape)
print(Y.shape)
df1=pd.read_csv('test.csv')
a=np.array(df1['x'],dtype=np.int)
b=np.array(df1['y'],dtype=np.float)
a=a.reshape(1,-1)
b=b.reshape(1,-1)
print(a.shape)
print(b.shape)
classifier=LinearRegression()
classifier.fit(X,Y)
accu=classifier.score(a,b) #throws error at this line
```

classifier.score gives an error that shapes are not aligned. 
  X.shape 1,700
  Y.shape  1,700
  a.shape 1,300
  b.shape 1,300
  But it shows:
  **ValueError:shapes (1,300) and (700,700) not aligned: 300 (dim 
  1) != 700 (dim 0).**

Comment: The code looks fine. I could not reproduce the error.

Comment: @Jones1220 I tried executing it one more time, but same error.

Comment: @Jones1220  And why is it showing (700,700) for X and Y, but (1,300) for a and b.

Comment: Are you possibly trying this in a Jyputer notebook? (plus, I have been trying to edit your code to *enhance readability* - please do not edit it back!)

Comment: @desertnaut No, I am using Visual Studio Code for writing the code and powershell to execute.

Comment: @Shikhar Dwivedi I don't know. I have used the boston data as example data that comes with sklearn and tried to reproduce your error. But everything works fine in my jupyter notebook.